# convergence in metric spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be sequences in a metric space $(X, d)$. Show that if $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ and $(b_n)$ converges to $b$, then $(d(a_n, b_n))$ converges to $d(a, b)$.

Comment: In a previous question, I have already proved for $a, b, c\in (X, d)$, we have $|d(a, c) − d(b, c)| \leq d(a, b)$. I think this may help, but I could not find a way to apply this.

Comment: Hint: You want show that $| d(a_n, b_n) - d(a,b) | \to 0$.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to show. Can you give me more hint?

Comment: ... $-d(a_n,b) + d(a_n,b)$ ...

Comment: Ohhhh, then use triangle inequality and the thing I proved before, right?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d(a,b)\leq d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)+d(b_n,b)\implies$ $$(1). \quad d(a,b)-d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a,a_n)+d(b_n,b).$$   $d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a_n,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_n)\implies$ $$ (2). \quad d(a_n,b_n)-d(a,b)\leq d(a_n,a)+d(b,b_n).$$ From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $$(3). \quad  |d(a,b)-d(a_n,b_n)|\leq  d(a,a_n)+d(b,b_n).$$ And the RHS of (3) converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

SF$d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a_n,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_n) $. For every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $d(a_n,a)<c/2$ and $d(b_n,b)<c/2$. This implies that for $n>N$, $d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a,b)+c$.

We also have

$d(a,b)\leq d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)+d(b_n,b)$. This implies that for $n>N$, $d(a,b)\leq d(a_n,b_n)+c.$ We deduce that $lim_nd(a_n,b_n)$ exists and is $d(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $(d(a_n,b_n))_n$ is a sequence in $\Bbb{R}$.

Given $\varepsilon >0$, you want to show that there exists $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n>n_0 \Longrightarrow |d(a_n,b_n)-d(a,b)|<\varepsilon.$$

Ps.: Write specifically what $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ means.

Comment: thanks, though i've finished the proof, it's very helpful.